# vue transpiled text in headings - accessibility

Tags: vue.js, accessibility

Im working through an accessibility audit for one of our sites. One of the things that has came back is empty headers where we have used vue for the text content. The audit is not seeing the rendered content and is hightlighting this as an issue. Does anyone have any ideas as to a solution?

```
<h3 v-html="post.title.rendered"></h3>
```

This is seen as an empty h3

Comment: Is the text-content actually there in the rendered HTML?

Comment: yes the text is rendered, Im hoping this is not an actual issue and its maybe getting picked up due to some automated test. (the audit is via an external company)

Comment: I imagine it depends on the company

Comment: What tool are you using to do this audit? If there's actually text in the DOM and your tool isn't picking that up, then it sounds like something isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I found an link here that helps

[Screen readers and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442849/screen-readers-and-javascript)

Thanks for the replies